# Finding the cube root of a quadratic binomial surd

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to find the cube root of quadratic binomial surds?

$\sqrt[3] {\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}=???$

I don't even know where to turn.

Edited:show that 
$\sqrt[3]{{3\sqrt{21}+8} } - \sqrt[3]{{3\sqrt{21}-8} }=1$
This is the case I have @KingW
However, there maybe different techniques to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have a particular case perhaps?

Comment: @kingW Yes I do. I have presented it in my edited post

Comment: With something like this I think your best bet will actually be to do something other than trying to deal with cube roots directly; there are likely neat subtleties found by trying other things.

Comment: @Dan Uznanski. I have tried other techniques but I'm making headways

Comment: Try $(u-v)^3$  and find what $uv$ is (where u, v are the radicals you have) and based on that try to find $u-v$.

Comment: Oh, hang on. This one might actually be nice... Turns out these numbers are themselves actually quadratic surds.  I don't know how to get there from here though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later did this:

$\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}+8} -\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}-8} =1$

$\\
\mathrm{let}\;\;\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}+8} =\sqrt{b}+a;\quad\mathrm{conversely:\;} 
\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}-8} =\sqrt{b} - a\\$

$\left(\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}+8}\right) ^3=(\sqrt{b}+a)^3;\quad \color{red} {3\sqrt{21} +8=(a+\sqrt{b})^3} \cdots(i) \\$

$\left(\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}-8}\right) ^3=(\sqrt{b}-a)^3;\quad \color{red} {3\sqrt{21} - 8=(\sqrt{b}-a)^3} \cdots(ii)
\\$

$(3\sqrt{21})^2-8^2 =(\sqrt{b}-a)^3(\sqrt{b}+a)^3=\left((\sqrt{b}-a)(\sqrt{b}+a)\right) ^3\\$

$189-64=(b-a^2)^3;\quad 125=(b-a^2)^3\quad 5=b-a^2\quad \\\boxed{b=a^2+5 \cdots(*)}$ $\\;\mathrm{Again;}\;\\$

$3\sqrt{21} +8=(a+\sqrt{b})^3=a^3+3a^2\sqrt{b}+3ab+b\sqrt b\\$

$\boxed{a^3+3ab=8\cdots(**)} \\$

$a^3+3a(a^2+5)=8\quad a^3+3a^3+15a=8\quad 4a^3 +15a-8=0\\$

$a=\frac{1} {2}, \;a\in\mathbb{C} \quad
 b=\left( \frac{1} {2} \right) ^2 +5=\frac{9}{4}\\$
$\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}+8} -\sqrt[3] {3\sqrt{21}-8}=a+\sqrt{b} - (\sqrt{b}-a) =2a=2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=1\\$

Answer (score 1):

This is another reason why you should always post exactly what you wanted to solve originally. Here, for example, you don't need to calculate cube roots. Just cube. Call the LHS $K.$ Then we want to show that $K=1.$

Cubing $K=\text{LHS}$ gives $K^3=16-3(9\cdot21-8^2)^{1/3}K,$ or after rearranging, $$K^3+15K-16=F(K)=0.$$

Taking $K=1$ satisfies this equality. Well, if you want to be completely puritanical about it, factorise $F(K)$ as $(K-1)(K^2+K+16)$ and note that the second factor cannot have real roots.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I would love a way to move from the LHS to RHS.

Comment: @OrestesDante That's exactly what I showed you. Oh, well, I think you mean a *direct* sequence of transformations from LHS to RHS. I don't know why you want this specifically, but that would mean extracting those cube roots, then simplifying the result, and so on. I think the main step here is extracting the cube roots of those quadratic surds. Unfortunately, that involves much more messier work in my opinion. The easiest way I see to do this presently is to develop the terms on LHS in series, and show that they sum to $1.$ Good luck! :)

Comment: @Orestes Dante: *I would love a way to move from the LHS to RHS* --- I don't believe a way exists (subject to certain precisely defined constraints that capture the essence of what you want), and probably an understanding of the issues involved goes back to the existence of the [*Casus Irreducibilis* case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis) for cubic equations, since I believe non-real complex numbers can be considered as quadratic surds (e.g. $3+2i = 3 + 2\sqrt{-1}).$ [This google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cube+root+of+complex%22) might be helpful.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro I added an answer based on my later findings.